# TextWatcher, how to detect a word when the cursor is between any of the letters?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I am using a TextWatcher to keep track of edittext words. What I would like is to be able to detect when a word is written and then a character is added to the start of the word.

For example, I want to type "hello" and in the moment that "hello" is finished I need to add a "-" prefix, so the final word would be "-hello".

I am not sure if this can be done with a TextWatcher. Can it, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to detect a `word` then you have to detect that the user has `pressed the space` button upon this you can simply add the `character` at the `start of the word`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just check whether the user entered the letters matches your predefined specified word list and then simply add the '-'